# Maximising battery longevity: when to charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a question that came to me with my new M1 MBP, running Monterey 12.5

The laptop warns me I need to plug in at 10%.  My previous laptop, a late 2013 MBP with Mojave, warned me at 5%.  Once upon a time I was told by a friend that is an electronic engineer to recharge a battery as late as possible (say 1% of charge remaining), but that was a long time ago, and said advice might not apply to modern (2022) batteries.  In any case, I used that advice (drain the battery as much as you can) for the old laptop, and it still managed about 1 hour of netflix streaming unplugged by the end of its life..

So, what is the best 'remaining charge' level to aim for before plugging in to maximise battery longevity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking the "best" remaining charge level to reach before plugging in to maximize battery longevity would be around 40%, and then charging it up to about 50% or 60%.

This isn't really practical however, and the actual benefits become less noticable the closer to 50% you keep your charge level.

Keeping the charge level **between 20% to 80%** will significantly increase the number of useful charge cycles you get from a lithium battery.

> Once upon a time I was told by a friend that is an electronic engineer to recharge a battery as late as possible (say 1% of charge remaining)

This would apply to nickel-cadmium chemistry batteries, which haven't  been used widely in laptops for a couple of decades.

Side note: Apple often over reports charge levels by a few %. When you take your laptop off charge from full it will report as 100% for a few minutes so when you see 99% charge level reported that's likely to be closer to 96% actual charge.